# How I can I start a powershell command line from a batch file and enforce it to stay open?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How I can I start a powershell session from a batch file so that it starts the **Powershell command line** (and imports some modules and then) stays open instead being closed once the commands are run in the bat. So that I can continue to work on the PS Shell command line with the modules imported.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

`-noexit` will stop powershell for terminating.

```
start powershell.exe -noexit
```

Comment: And can I run it by also providing a powershell script file?

Comment: yes it should work fine. `start powershell.exe -noexit -file <script>`